# Cross Site Scripting (XSS) error

Tags: browser, html, javascript

My website seems to producing a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) error.  I would appreciate advice on how to cure it.

As ususal the key question is what have I just changed?  The answer is added Facebook 'Like' buttons to my web pages. I am wondering if there is a conflict with the Google+1 code that I added about 2 months previously?

What can I do with my html (javascript) code to prevent this IE 8 / 9 Browser message, while keeping my Facebook and Google+1 buttons?

Comment: helpful information here ... http://64.215.254.44/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=30001 ?

Comment: Code

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=185802801489096&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Will-and-Guy-Jokes/125767604187628" send="false" layout="button_count" width="0" show_faces="false" action="like" google-analytics="UA-2653530-1" font="">

</fb:like>

[link](http://guy-sports.com)

Comment: Blow me!  This morning there is no Cross Site Scripting error.  As soon as I see it again I will post.

Meanwhile I am developing a new theory, and trying to get a handle of the extent of the problem.  e.g. Just me, other visitors.